# What in the lore makes Krakens immune to lightning?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, lore, immunities

I don't understand, thematically, why a sea creature would be immune to lightning. Where exactly does a Kraken gain its immunity to lightning from? My players are going to fight a Kraken soon and I'd like to be able to say something other than "your lightning bolt deals no damage" if a player uses a lightning spell but explain the in-universe reasoning for it.

Comment: Of note: Kraken did not have this immunity when initially appearing in 1E, say. Arguably closer to mythology source before being fully game-ified.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Are you looking for lore within the books, or a narrative response?

Comment: How is this opinion based? Voting to reopen - this is a pretty standard lore question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Krakens have powers that relate to lightning and storms

The Kraken as described in the 5e Monster Manual has a Lightning Storm ability that can shoot lightning bolts around it. A monster being resistant to the kind of energy it throws around all the time is pretty standard. In addition to that, one of the Kraken's lair abilities charges the water with electricity, and one of its regional effects allows it to *control weather* -- and I'm assuming it isn't going to aim for balmy sunshine!

Basically, krakens are a giant legendary monster that represents the power of a storm at sea in addition to the terrors of the deep. Resistance to lightning follows from that.

Comment: it makes even more sense than with other creatures, because realistically, you don't want to emit electric shocks underwater if you're not immune to them ^^

Comment: Curiously, the best natural analog, the electric eel, is actually [quite vulnerable to even its own electric shocks](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2018/04/03/how-do-eels-generate-electricity-in-water-without-electrocuting-themselves/?sh=17492a8b64a0) and they've even been known to accidentally kill themselves with their own electric shocks.